# How can I fetch data NOT IN another query array using PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

From the second query, I want to get users whose id are not in the first query. Please how do i run this? Below is what I have done so far. The final goal is to get IDs in this format in the first query Example: "1", "2","3" etc and this IDs should not be part of the second second query.

```
 $followpeople = $conne->prepare('SELECT thisuser from followerstable where ids = :ids ');
```

$followpeople->execute(array("ids "=>$ids ));
$followers = $followpeople->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

```
$users = $conne->prepare(" SELECT * FROM usersdb LEFT JOIN followerstable p ON r.ids = p.ids where r.ids NOT IN ('" . implode("', '", $followers["thisuser"])."') order by rand() LIMIT 3;");
```

Comment: You need to explain the **final goal**, the data you need. Because right now neither query makes any sense, so we cannot tell what you actually want

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do the first Query,

just directly query in `usersdb` table and left join it to the `followerstable`
if the `ids` in `followerstable` is null it means it doesn't exist in `followerstable`

```
$users = $conne->prepare("SELECT * FROM usersdb r LEFT JOIN followerstable p ON r.ids = p.ids where p.ids IS NULL order by rand() LIMIT 3;");
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't get my questions. First I want to get all the IDs a user is following in the first query. Then after that, those IDs should not be part of the second query.

Comment: I expect your first query is already correct, right? In the second query you wanted to fetch the users that are not in `followerstable`  base on the result of your first query?

Comment: Why are you guys preparing a statement with no parameters in it?

Comment: Yes, users that are not in the followerstsble only but based on a user not for all users.   To clarify, if a user has followed a group of users before, he should not see them again but other users can as well see them since they have not follow before

Comment: For example, In the first query, the variable $followers will contain arrays of IDs in this format "1", "2", "3"   and these IDs should not be part of the second query

Comment: @Austin for starter, your first query never works as intended. And as soon as you manage it to get working, I don't see how it's a problem go get the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NOT IN (SELECT) construction, so you don't need two statements. I assume the IDs in *usersdb* and *followerstable* mean the same person.

```
$users = $conne->prepare("SELECT * FROM usersdb WHERE ids NOT IN (SELECT ids FROM followerstable where ids = :ids) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
```

Or if the matching IDs are *ids* in *usersdb* and *thisuser* in *followerstable*, then it would be:

```
$users = $conne->prepare("SELECT * FROM usersdb WHERE ids NOT IN (SELECT thisuser FROM followerstable where ids = :ids) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: Why are you guys are preparing a statement with a single placeholder when apparently it requires many values to be bound?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't care for the WHERE clause, so I just repeated what the OP did. And he used an one element array. But I agree to you, this doesn't make very much sense. I suggest, an another IN clause in the inner SELECT is needed. It's not that clear what the OP really wants to do. For me, the task was: Can we put this one together in one SQL statement (to maybe avoid a loop).